# Does IntelliJ IDEA or JetBrains products run on windows rt or Microsoft surface rt?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, arm

I have just being informed that the Microsoft's surface rt tablet, due to it's ARM based processor design, provides with a very poor support for previous legendary windows based applications such as VlC or etc. Now, what I just wanted to know is can you install and run INTELLIJ or eclipse or other famous programming IDES on windows rt, or on an ARM based device?
Thanks a lot for response.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. IntelliJ IDEA and other products based on the IntelliJ platform are Java SWING applications and require JDK to run.

As far as I know, there is no Java for Windows RT. [See this meta answer](https://superuser.com/a/497439/4777) with other links.